# Call specific Azure Function from Event Hub message

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We have an Azure Function project written in Node/JavaScript in which we have a few functions and some of them needs to be called after the other. Currently we're using timeTriggers with some time difference, so that function A gets called and then function B gets called knowing that function A have already been called; the problem is that sometimes there's a delay between these calls and I don't know if function A got executed correctly. One solution that I found was having function A execute, then output an event to an Event Hub, which then  triggers function B using an eventHubTrigger.Now, the problem is that I don't know how to route the messages to specific functions. Some examples of expected behaviour/use cases:

```
Function A finishes -> Calls function B
Function C finishes -> Calls function D

Function A finishes ->
 if data was correctly saved call function B
 if data was NOT correctly saved call function D
```

**PLAN B:**

I have also thought about having blobTriggers do this. Having function A save empty data to a blob which triggers function B via blobTriggers, but we've seen up to 20 minutes delay between function A saving data to the blob and function B getting triggered. Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to tightly couple these functions, you can leverage [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) to create complex orchestrations in code, letting the underlying framework take care of durability and ensuring functions are run to completion.

If you rather not couple them like so, you can use [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) as a Message Broker and setup the secondary functions to trigger on Service Bus Messages, creating separate queues per function.

For complex scenarios, you can also look into [chaining entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) within Service Bus to have a single output message be copied over to multiple queues and trigger multiple functions, if required.